# how to convert from json to object of my class & vise versa (with alamofire, SwiftyJSON)

Tags: ios, json, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using Swift 2 with xcode 7.3.1.

I have [Alamofire 3.4](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) & [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) in my project. I know I can convert the response result value from Alamofire to `JSON`(a structure defined by SwiftyJSON) type by using following code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success:
        if let value = response.result.value {
          // now I get JSON type object, then what?
          let json = JSON(value)
          print("JSON: \(json)")
        }
    case .Failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

My question is after I get `json`, how can I convert it to an object of a custom class ?

For example, the `json` has the following structure:

```
{"name": 
 "Kate", 
 "age": 23, 
 "books":[{"id":1,"name":"book-1"},{"id":2,"name":"book-2"}]
}
```

I have a Swift class:

```
class Student {
  var name: String!
  var age: Int!
  var books:[Book]
  ...
}

class Book {
  var id: Int!
  var name: String!
  ...
}
```

How can I convert `json` to `Student` object and vise versa with the Alamofire & SwiftyJSON ?

(I am newbie in iOS, I just found people on internet suggested these two libraries for JSON response handling, so I use them. Please point me out if it is not necessary or if there is other efficient way to achive it. Thanks in advance.)

Comment: SwiftyJSON, if possible, converts an HTTP response into a dictionary-like object called `JSON`. That's all there is. It is your job to map the JSON object to an actual model in your app. You might want to use [`AlamofireObjectMapper`](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) over SwiftyJSON at this point to save yourself the mess of doing that mapping.

Comment: @ozgur, I checked the link of AlamofireObjectMapper, it looks like I don't need to use SwiftyJSON to convert string to `JSON`. It directly do this `Alamofire.request(.GET, URL).responseObject { (response: Response<Student, NSError>)`, you see, it allow me to have the `Student` type and convert directly to my object. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: But it looks like AlamofireObjectMapper is a one way mapping, it can't convert object to json or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the transform methods of json data in the **Book** and **Student** struct, use **Struct** instead of **Class** in Swift. And I write some sample code,

```
struct Book {
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    static func booksFromJSONArray(jsonArray: [JSON]) -> [Book]? {
        return jsonArray.flatMap{ jsonItem -> Book in
            guard let id = jsonItem["id"].int,
                let name = jsonItem["name"].string
             else { return nil }

            return Book(id: id, name: name)
    }
}


struct Student {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var books: [Book]

    func studentFromJSONData(jsonData: JSON) -> Student {
        let name = jsonData["name"].stringValue
        let age = jsonData["age"].intValue
        let books = Book.booksFromJSONArray(jsonData["books"].arrayValue)

        return Student(name: name, age: age, books: books)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't use Class type to do the same? I don't get it. Besides, struct is value type, class is reference type, I prefer to use Class for my objects for this reason.

Comment: Yes, u r right. Struct is value type passed by copied value, and class is reference type passed by a reference. In Swift, Apple is recommend to use value type. You can see the WWDC2015session 408: Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift and session 414:Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift for more information.